# Вопрос по кукам

Tags: php, cookie

Подскажите, почему кнопки голосования выводятся даже после голосования и как исправить? Первый раз работаю с куками.

```
<?php
        function showRes()
        {
            $idZaNov = fopen('php/golos/zaNov.txt', 'r');
            $infZaNov = fgets($idZaNov, 999);
            echo "<br />"."За Новороссию - ".$infZaNov."<br />";
            $idZaUkr = fopen('php/golos/zaUkr.txt', 'r');
            $infZaUkr = fgets($idZaUkr, 999);
            echo "За Единую украину - ".$infZaUkr;
            fclose($idZaNov);
            fclose($idZaUkr);
        }
        function addRes ($addTamp)
        {
            if($addTamp == 1)
            {
                $idZaNov = fopen('php/golos/zaNov.txt', 'r');
                $infZaNov = fgets($idZaNov, 999);
                $oldResNov = $infZaNov;
                fclose($idZaNov);
                $idZaNov = fopen("php/golos/zaNov.txt", "w");
                fwrite($idZaNov, $oldResNov+1); 
                fclose($idZaNov);
                $_SESSION['golo'] == "Nov"; 
            }
            else if ($addTamp == 2)
            {
                $idZaUkr = fopen('php/golos/zaUkr.txt', 'r');
                $infZaUkr = fgets($idZaUkr, 999);
                $oldResUkr = $infZaUkr;
                fclose($idZaUkr);
                $idZaUkr = fopen("php/golos/zaUkr.txt", "w");
                fwrite($idZaUkr, $oldResUkr+1); 
                fclose($idZaUkr);
                $_SESSION['golo'] == "Ukr";
            }
        }
        if ($_SESSION['golo'] == "Nov")
        {
            echo "Вы уже голосовали - за Новороссию";
            showRes();
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['golo'] == "Ukr")
        {
            echo "Вы уже голосовали - за Новороссию";
            showRes();
        }
        elseif ($_SESSION['golo'] == NULL)
        {
                    if(isset($_REQUEST['nov']) )
                    {
                        echo('Вы проголосовали за: Новороссию');
                        showRes();
                        addRes (1);
                    }
                    else if (isset($_REQUEST['ukr']))
                    {
                        echo('Вы проголосовали за: Единую Украины');
                        showRes();
                        addRes (2);
                    }
                        else 
                    {
        }
    ?>
        <form method="POST">
        <input type='submit' name="nov" value="Новороссия" >
        <input type='submit' name="ukr" value="Объеденная Украина" >
        </form>
    <?PHP
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: @mkrichet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все очень плохо. Опустим едкий комментарий, что накрутка рейтинга в голосовании по кукам - это дело только маленького времени.

Перейдем к сути.
1) Если у вас нет автосоздания сессии, надо в самом начале прописать функцию

```
session_start();
```

До ЛЮБОГО вывода.
2) В сессию у вас ничего не заносится.

```
$_SESSION['golo'] == "Ukr";
```

Будет СРАВНИВАТЬ сессионную переменную и строку. Надо один знак равенства.

3)

```
 if ($_SESSION['golo'] == "Nov")
    {
        echo "Вы уже голосовали - за Новороссию";
        showRes();
    }
    elseif ($_SESSION['golo'] == "Ukr")
    {
        echo "Вы уже голосовали - за Новороссию";
        showRes();
    }
```

Украинцы, голосовавшие за Украину будут счастливы...